# Trying to count across two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables like so:

Resources

```
ID | Resource
1  | 1234
2  | 1356
3  | 1456
```

Products

```
ID | Product
1  | North
1  | South
1  | West
2  | North
3  | East
3  | West
```

I'd like to achieve a count of the number of Products each Resource is used on so that the result is:

```
Resource | Products
1234     | 3
1356     | 1
1456     | 2
```

The SQL I have written is:

```
SELECT R.Resource, count (P.Product) as Products
from Resource R
left join Product P on R.ID = P.ID
GROUP BY R.Resource, P.Product;
```

But this is giving the following result

```
Resource | Product
1234     | 1
1234     | 1
1234     | 1
1356     | 1
1456     | 1
1456     | 1
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `COUNT` and `GROUP BY` as you did but with an `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT r."Resource", COUNT(p."Product") AS Products
FROM Resources r
INNER JOIN Products p ON r."ID" = p."ID"
GROUP BY r."Resource"
```

Output

```
Resource PRODUCTS
1356     1
1456     2
1234     3
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7c01a/27/0